# R, for each loop, value, interval

Tags: r, sorting, for-loop, foreach, tidyverse

I have a dataset about animals.
Including the answer below, I update my concern.

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- c("Date", "Specie", "Number")
b <- c("2020-01-01", "Dog", "3")
c <- c("2020-01-02", "Dog", "4")
d <- c("2020-01-03", "Dog", "5")
e <- c("2020-01-04", "Dog", "6")
f <- c("2020-01-01", "Cat", "3")
g <- c("2020-01-02", "Cat", "7")
h <- c("2020-01-03", "Cat", "8")
i <- c("2020-01-04", "Cat", "10")

df <- as.data.frame(rbind(b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i))
names(df) <- a
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
df$Number <- as.integer(df$Number)

start <- as.Date("2020-01-02")
end <- as.Date("2020-01-04")

df %>%
  filter(Date >= start & Date <= end) %>%
  group_by(Specie) %>% 
  summarise(new = prod(10 + Number), .groups = "drop")
```

The goal is to create a new variable that gives me: (using tidyverse)
For each specie, between 2020-01-02 and 2020-01-04 (included), I want a new variable that is the product of (10+number of dead animals that day).
For-example, for dogs it would be (10+4)*(10+5)*(10+6).
Same for all specie.

Please note that for some specie, I don't have the number of dead animals during all the days of the interval.

- Is dropping them the best option?
  If yes, how do you do it.

Note that the code filters and hence keeps only my dataset for the dates specify. I want to return the output that the code delivers but in my original dataset.

- That is, the output I get should be a new variable (mutate) for all species. And not a subset of my dataset.
  I did a left-join to merge the original dataset with the new (filtered) one. It works, but I think there's a more efficient way.

Thank's for your help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way.
I have created start and end dates variables to make the code more general purpose.
Filter by date first, then compute aggregated products with `prod`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

a <- c("Date", "Specie", "Number")
b <- c("2020-01-01", "Dog", "3")
c <- c("2020-01-02", "Dog", "4")
d <- c("2020-01-03", "Dog", "5")
e <- c("2020-01-04", "Dog", "6")
f <- c("2020-01-01", "Cat", "3")
g <- c("2020-01-02", "Cat", "7")
h <- c("2020-01-03", "Cat", "8")
i <- c("2020-01-04", "Cat", "10")

df <- as.data.frame(rbind(b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i))
names(df) <- a
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
df$Number <- as.integer(df$Number)

start <- as.Date("2020-01-02")
end <- as.Date("2020-01-04")

df %>%
  filter(Date >= start & Date <= end) %>%
  group_by(Specie) %>% 
  summarise(new = prod(10 + Number), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Specie   new
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 Cat     6120
#> 2 Dog     3360
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Almost there. I want to create a new variable in my original dataset that is this rate of growth. "new" in your notation. However, if I replace summarise by "mutate" then I only have a subset of my dataset. That is, only between 01-02 and 01-04. I lose all other observations.

Comment: Hence, how do I compute this rate, add it to my orginal dataset, without losing any observation. For the dates that are not between 01-02 and 01-04, I want the value 'new' to be matched.

Comment: I did a left join but I think there's a more efficient way