# R, rate of growth, different time

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following example of dataset for a biology project.
I want to compute a rate of growth of number between 4th January and 2nd of January.
That is rate = (number_at_0104 - number_at_0102)/(number_at_0102)
(In tidyverse if possible)

```
a <- c("Date", "Specie", "Number")
b <- c("2020-01-01", "Dog", "3")
c <- c("2020-01-02", "Dog", "4")
d <- c("2020-01-03", "Dog", "5")
e <- c("2020-01-04", "Dog", "6")
f <- c("2020-01-01", "Cat", "3")
g <- c("2020-01-02", "Cat", "7")
h <- c("2020-01-03", "Cat", "8")
i <- c("2020-01-04", "Cat", "10")

df <- as.data.frame(rbind(b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i))
names(df) <- a
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
df$Number <- as.integer(df$Number)
```

I want to calculate a rate of growth. I know this has been treated already but I'm not sure whether I can apply it there.
Usually, we use the lag() function but I have some questions.

- Can we tell the lag function what lags to use (eg not the previous periods but 4 periods before)
- My dataset is much bigger and for some specie (say cat) I want to compute the rate of growth between 20 Feb and 3 March. And for others (say dog) I want to compute between 5 May and 4th April. How can I do it?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: So your desired output is a single number of rate?

Comment: Yes, for each specie I want a rate of growth. However, I want the reference dates to change between specie. Ex dog and cat have different ending and starting dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**using dplyr**

```
start <- as.Date("2020-01-02")
end <- as.Date("2020-01-04")

df %>%
  filter(Date %between% c(start, end)) %>%
  arrange(Date, Species) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(Growth = (last(Number) - first(Number)) / first(Number))
```

**output**

```
  Species Growth
  <fct>    <dbl>
1 Cat       0.25
2 Dog       0.5
```

**data**
*note that my test data is already as dates and as numeric values*

```
df <- data.frame(
  Date = rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-04"), "days"), 2),
  Species = c(rep("Dog", 4), rep("Cat", 4)),
  Number = 3:10
)
```

**if you want different lookups for every species** you can do something like this. Define your lookups and the output will be a tibble with Species, Growth and the period it was taken from.

```
lookups <- list(
  c("Species" = "Dog", "start" = "2020-01-01", "end" = "2020-01-04"),
  c("Species" = "Cat", "start" = "2020-01-02", "end" = "2020-01-04")
)

bind_rows(lapply(lookups, function(species) {
  df %>%
  filter(Species == species["Species"] & Date %between% as.Date(c(species["start"], species["end"]))) %>%
  arrange(Date, Species) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(
    Growth = (last(Number) - first(Number)) / first(Number),
    Start = species["start"],
    End = species["end"]
  )
}))


# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Species Growth Start      End       
#   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     
# 1 Dog       1    2020-01-01 2020-01-04
# 2 Cat       0.25 2020-01-02 2020-01-04
```

Comment: Without specifying more, I don't think this will provide the expected result. It will take the first value of the list and the last. But I don't want this necessarily.

Comment: Just order by date first if that is not always the case.

Comment: also added the filter as I missed your note to calculate from 2nd to 4th of January.

Comment: The function %between% is in the base dplyr? I have an error that "x could not find the function between"

Comment: yes `%between%` is part of dplyr

Comment: Perfect ! can I ask you to take a look on this question. Someone answered but in my comments, you can see that there's a pb. stackoverflow.com/questions/70940035/… Thank's

Comment: Not sure what you exactly want from this question versus the other question you refer to.  Perhaps the best is to update your code with what you learned from both answers and then ask a new question from the point you get stuck again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)

start_date <- as.Date("2020-01-02")
end_date <- as.Date("2020-01-04")

df %>%
  group_by(Specie) %>%
  summarise(growth_rate = (Number[match(end_date, Date)] - 
                           Number[match(start_date, Date)])/
                           Number[match(start_date, Date)])

#  Specie growth_rate
#  <chr>        <dbl>
#1 Cat          0.429
#2 Dog          0.5
```

You can replace the `start_date` and  `end_date` with the dates of your choice.

Or maybe a bit verbose but clearer answer would be -

```
df %>%
  group_by(Specie) %>%
  summarise(num_end = Number[match(end_date, Date)], 
            num_start = Number[match(start_date, Date)], 
            growth_rate = (num_end - num_start)/num_start)

#  Specie num_end num_start growth_rate
#  <chr>    <int>     <int>       <dbl>
#1 Cat         10         7       0.429
#2 Dog          6         4       0.5
```

Comment: can I ask you to take a look on this question. Someone answered but in my comments, you can see that there's a pb. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70940035/r-for-each-loop-value-interval/70940320#70940320 Thank's